# Open angular ui modal on ajax loaded select

Tags: angularjs, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm loading the dropdown with jsonp, the dropdown is populated from the url, but when I select an option 1, it should open a dialog with some rules in it. I'm trying to make this work, but no luck.

I was following the [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) modal code and this from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641918/not-able-to-open-modal-box-selecting-value-from-the-dropdown-using-ui-bootstrap)

```
<div class="table-cell" ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <select id="method" ng-change="open();" ng-model="selected">
      <option>
        --select--
      </option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in items" value={{item.id}}>{{item.value}} </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Results <small>Total Records: <strong>{{allrecords.length}}</strong></small></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Your selection: {{selected}}</p>
      <p>Displaying records: {{startval}} - {{endval}}</p>
      <ol start="{{startval}}">
        <li ng-repeat="record in allrecords.slice(startval-1, endval)">{{record.Name}}</li>
        <ol>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Angular

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']),
  dropDown = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', []);

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
  console.log($scope);
  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
  $scope.open = function(size) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

dropDown.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: 'URL?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
    withCredentials: true
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```